# Choose values from different columns depending on another column into a new column

Tags: r

I have this sample data called `df`:

```
     Value1     Value2     Identifier
1   0.01544308 9.984557    high
2   0.02857169 9.971428    high
3   0.02767568 9.972324    low
4   0.03003700 9.969963    high
5   0.02779373 9.972206    low
6   0.02869768 9.971302    high
```

I now want to create a new column with a combined value depending on the content of the identifier column. 
If the Identifier value is "high", I want to have Value1 in the new column, if it's "low" I want Value2 in the new column.

I've tried it with this code:

```
> df$Score <-0 
> df$Score[df$Identifier == "high"] <- df$Value1
> df$Score[df$Identifier == "low"] <- df$Value2
```

This is kind of working but I get this Error Message:

> 4: In df$Score[df$Identifier == "high"] <- df$Value1 :   number of
>   items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length 
>   5: In df$Score[df$Identifier == "low"] <- df$Value2 :   number of items to
>   replace is not a multiple of replacement length

When I check the values in the new column `Score` , it worked well for Value1 but not quite right for Value2.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there maybe a completely different approach? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try `df$Score <- ifelse(df$Identifier == "high", df$Value1, df$Value2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducible example:

```
> df = data.frame(v1=runif(10), v2=runif(10)+100, id=sample(c("High","Low"),10,TRUE))
> df
          v1       v2   id
1  0.5369817 100.7348 High
2  0.4603543 100.2849  Low
3  0.7916333 100.3077 High
4  0.9786784 100.6317  Low
5  0.9116897 100.6764  Low
6  0.3311296 100.5460 High
7  0.4623154 100.5480  Low
8  0.5737816 100.1262 High
9  0.3905863 100.0561  Low
10 0.6010738 100.3528  Low
```

What you want is an `ifelse`:

```
> df$Score = ifelse(df$id=="High",df$v1,df$v2)
> df
          v1       v2   id       Score
1  0.5369817 100.7348 High   0.5369817
2  0.4603543 100.2849  Low 100.2848737
3  0.7916333 100.3077 High   0.7916333
4  0.9786784 100.6317  Low 100.6316633
5  0.9116897 100.6764  Low 100.6763961
6  0.3311296 100.5460 High   0.3311296
7  0.4623154 100.5480  Low 100.5479902
8  0.5737816 100.1262 High   0.5737816
9  0.3905863 100.0561  Low 100.0561174
10 0.6010738 100.3528  Low 100.3527770
```